# How To Assign Instance ID When Initializing LoaderManager

Tags: android, android-loadermanager, asynctaskloader

In order to use AsynTaskLoader, I first need to initialize LoaderManger. The first argument is a unique ID (integer) of the instance.

- Is there a best practice to assign each ID?
- Is it simple as several examples I found and assign it 0 or 1?
- Do I need to worry about instances clashing with each other?

Below is an example code with ID set to 0.

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly to use AsyncTaskLoader you need to initialize corresponding Loader and not LoaderManager.

- Is there a best practice to assign each ID?
- Is it simple as several examples I found and assign it 0 or 1?

You should declare ID as constants like -

```
private static final int TASK_A = 1;
private static final int TASK_B = 2;
```

- Do I need to worry about instances clashing with each other?

No, even if you call initLoader again being called before it just skips the onCreateLoader method and directly calls onLoadFinished with cached copy of previous data

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that Loader is initialized. As for your answer about instance clashing, that is what I am worried about. What happens when I start a loader in one activity with TASK_A (ID 1) then I go to another activity and it starts another loader with TASK_X (ID 1) but which is a different task. What would happen then? How will the loader know to return data back to correct activity that called it?

Comment: When initializing TASK_A Loader like - 

getLoaderManager().initLoader(TASK_A, null, this);

3rd argument 'this' passed is LoaderCallbacks

OnCreateLoader / OnLoadFinished defined in that Acitivity which LoaderCallbacks have implemented will get called.

So no point of clash even if you define TASK_X = 1 in some other Activity as the following call - 

getLoaderManager().initLoader(TASK_X, null, this);

will call OnCreateLoader / OnLoadFinished defined in that some other Acitivity which LoaderCallbacks have implemented

Comment: Now I understand that I do not need to worry about ID overlap, as long as values are not same within the activity/fragment. Thanks!